# while reading data from sqlite all the column names are coming in lower case in ionic app (IOS)

Tags: ios, sqlite, capacitor

I am trying to execute select query to read data from sqlite tables. but while reading data all the column names are coming in lower case in ios but its coming pascal case in android.

**createTableQuery = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (ID varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, FirstName varchar(255), LastName varchar(255),Address varchar(255),MobileNumber varchar(255));'**

**selectQuery = select * from TestTable;**

**this.sqlite.query(query, values);**

**query result- (ios)**

id, firstname, lastname, address, mobilenumber

**query result- (android)**

ID, FirstName, LastName, Address, MobileNumber

Please help me out to get same column name from sqlite table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can’t speak to Ionic, but `sqlite3_column_name` and `sqlite3_column_origin_name` on iOS definitely preserve the column capitalization (I just tested on iOS 13.5).

Comment: I’d suggest opening up the database in some third party tool (e.g. the `sqlite3` command line tool or whatever tool you prefer) and see if the column names are actually mixed case or not (your `CREATE` statement only creates table if it doesn’t exist, so we don’t know for sure whether there might have already been a table there). But, bottom line, confirm whether the problem is in the table creation, or in the retrieval of the column names.